# Restarting a stream on a chromecast receiver application

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

During bad network conditions and streaming failing I'd like to retry the stream after a while and try to recover it at the same position where it failed before network outage.

I have a receiver app based on the reference receiver app (https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample). I'm trying to simulate a sender load request by saving the last load request sent from the sender and calling my onLoad listener with the same request but an updated "currentTime" when I want to re-start streaming.

This seems to work fine except that it always starts from the beginning, ignoring the currentTime setting.

What is the correct way to restart a stream on a receiver application (without a trigger from a sender app) in a specific point in time?

I'm using Cast receiver v2.0.0, Media Player Library v1.0.0, adaptive bitrate streams (smooth streaming) and PlayReady DRM.

Answer (score 1):

Using the the initalTime param of the Player.load method seems to work fine.
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.Player#load

I.e. explicitly setting the initialTime yourself from the currentTime value in the load command (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/messages#Load)

I didn't notice the optional initialTime param of the load method earlier since the reference receiver app didn't use it (but still manages to start at the given time through some other non-obvious mechanism).

So what I'm essentially doing is saving the last load command, then listening to a network error (code = 3, https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.ErrorCode#.NETWORK) on the host object (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.Host#onError) and replaying the last load command with an updated currentTime. You can do this after a timeout, when the media element runs out its video buffer, or in reaction to a network reconnection event (which you'll have to create yourself).